# Single permission OS X ACL entries

Tags: macos, permissions, acl

I'm just trying to understand what happens when you apply a new ACL entry (specifying only a single permission) to a directory or file through the terminal.

For example if I were to run this to allow write access for all users in the `developers` group for all the found files and directories in the current directory:

```
sudo find . -exec chmod +a "developers allow write"
```

Would that then use a set of defaults to determine whether the user is able to say list the files in a directory, or would it fall back to checking against the traditional POSIX execute permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An action, say listing the files, only uses the ACL if you have specifically defined that permission as either **allow** or **deny**. Otherwise the normal POSIX permissions are used.

Thinking back I don't know why I didn't click on to that, it makes perfect sense.